# iOS simulators are not available in visual studio after updating xcode to version 14

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator, xcode14

Everything was working fine till updating Xcode to version 14. But after updating Xcode to latest version 14, simulators are not available in visual studio.

[image]

Also, app is not getting installed on physical devices. Just getting a success message as normally but the app is not on the device.

[image]

Comment: VS has not been updated for XCode 14 yet

Comment: This is a very annoying thing as the beta version was already available 2 months back and still VS team not able to make it work. Hope the issue will be fixed soon now.

Comment: You can check [this link](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/15954) which have a solution to use the XCode 14.

Answer (score 1):

I have downgraded the Xcode and now i am able to see all the simulators and deploy the Xamarin forms App on device and simulators.

Steps to Downgrade XCode:

1. Go to Apple developer site and login with your credentials .
2. Once you logged in into site, scroll down where you can see XCode 13.4.1 see the below screenshot

[XCode on Apple store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlN0h.png)

3. Click on download. Once it is downloaded kindly uninstall your previous XCode which on your mac and then install XCode 13.4.1.
4. Give the exact XCode path in Visual studio. Below is the screenshot for reference ---SDKManager

[Xamarin Forms App specific settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLnWE.png)

Now you can build the app and deploy your app in the simulators or mobiles.

Comment: Yes old Xcode working fine that I'm aware, but here we have an issue with the latest Xcode 14. Not able to test app with iOS 16 simulator or old with xcode 14.

Answer (score 1):

I got a new update today for Visual Studio for iOS16 and after updating VS all simulators are available now.

Answer (score 1):

Install Visual Studio 2022 for Mac. It works with Xcode 14 & iOS 16.